# Optimizing my image search routine

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search, image-processing

My routine is as follows (the `SpeedyBitmap` class just locks each bitmap for faster pixel data access):

```
    private static bool TestRange(int number, int lower, int upper) {
        return number >= lower && number <= upper;
    }

    public static List<Point> Search(Bitmap toSearch, Bitmap toFind, double percentMatch = 0.85, byte rTol = 2, byte gTol = 2, byte bTol = 2) {
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        int findArea = toFind.Width * toFind.Height;
        int allowedMismatches = findArea - (int)(findArea * percentMatch);
        int mismatches = 0;

        using (SpeedyBitmap speedySearch = new SpeedyBitmap(toSearch)) {
            using (SpeedyBitmap speedyFind = new SpeedyBitmap(toFind)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < speedySearch.Height - speedyFind.Height + 1; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < speedySearch.Width - speedyFind.Width + 1; j++) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < speedyFind.Height; k++) {
                            for (int l = 0; l < speedyFind.Width; l++) {
                                Color searchColor = speedySearch[j + l, i + k];
                                Color findColor = speedyFind[l, k];

                                if (!TestRange(searchColor.R, findColor.R - rTol, findColor.R + rTol) ||
                                    !TestRange(searchColor.G, findColor.G - gTol, findColor.G + gTol) ||
                                    !TestRange(searchColor.B, findColor.B - bTol, findColor.B + bTol)) {
                                    mismatches++;

                                    if (mismatches > allowedMismatches) {
                                        mismatches = 0;

                                        goto notFound;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        points.Add(new Point(j, i));

                        continue;

                        notFound:
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        return points;
    }
```

Searching a moderately sized image (1000x1000) takes over 20 seconds. Removing the percent match takes it down to a few hundred milliseconds, so I think I've established where the major bottleneck is.

How can I make this run faster? Perhaps I could flatten the two-dimensional arrays down to one-dimensional arrays and then apply some sort of sequence check on the two to possibly match up the longest sequence of where the `toFind` bitmap data appears with the respective tolerances and match percent. If this would be a good solution, how would I begin to implement it?

Comment: I don't really see how removing the percent match would make it run faster, except in the case where what you're searching for does not exist and you get a mismatch faster. If it exists, you will still execute everything with or without the percent matching.

Comment: As I understand, you are searching for a smaller image inside a bigger one. While speaking about 20sec processing, what is the size of the smaller and what of the bigger (it's unclear which one is 1000x1000). Also, what was the result (true/false)?